# how do i setup a local working directory to work with a local repo using Mercurial

Tags: mercurial

Following is the scenario: I have a remote Mercurial repository at `ssh://remotehost//dir/repo` and I am able to clone it to a local host "pandora" in directory `/home/user/localrepo/`.

Now, I have a superset of this remote repository, where I add my own testing framework, but do not want to merge to the main depot until I am certain it works. So I clone this "local" repo to `/home/user/workingdir/` but when I issue the command to do so

```
$ hg clone /home/user/localrepo/
```

only the repository folder gets copied none of the files get copied.

Comment: Are you certain that the files in the /localrepo/ directory are actually under SVN and not just in the folder? This is a long shot but seems like a possible issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean when you say that "only the repo folders gets copied". So there's two things you can try :

1. Try to do a `hg update` in your new clone.
2. List the directory in /home/user/workingdir and if there is a directory name localrepo in it, this is actually your repository. To clone in the current directory, you must do `hg clone /home/user/localrepo .`

Comment: by "repo folder getting copied" i mean only one directory name is copied over, and i tried the hg clone as: kahmed@pandora:~/workingdir$ hg clone /home/kahmed/localrepo/PrafQA .
updating to branch default
0 files updated, 0 files merged, 0 files removed, 0 files unresolved
kahmed@pandora:~/workingdir$ 
kahmed@pandora:~/workingdir$ ls -la
total 12
drwxr-xr-x  3 kahmed kahmed 4096 2011-02-28 16:10 .
drwxr-xr-x 40 kahmed kahmed 4096 2011-02-28 15:37 ..
drwxr-xr-x  3 kahmed kahmed 4096 2011-02-28 16:10 .hg
kahmed@pandora:~/workingdir$

Comment: yes hg update gives nothing, it seems i am missing somethign very basic

Comment: like commiting your code in the source repository like pointed in the other answer maybe ;)

Answer (score 0):

This sounds odd but try a few things:

First in the local repo that you cloned from do a

`hg status -A`

are all the files that you think should be in there in there? If not are you at the tip of the repo.

You can see what revision you are at with

`hg parent`

If you want to just go to the tip do `hg update`

If there still aren't any files listed in the repo do the same to check the one on the server.

If there aren't any files on the server you will need to `add` all of the files you want mercurial to track, mercurial doesn't automagically start tracking files in the repo location.

(Use `hg add --all` to add all of the file in the entire directory tree under the repo location.)

If there are files in the local repo, check the testing area and make sure that it is on the proper changeset.

Comment: hg status -A gives:A AUTHORS
A CHANGES
A MANIFEST.in
A Makefile
A NEWS
A TODO
A VERSION
A ez_setup.py
A setup.cfg
A setup.py
? bin/asteriskCallerDaemon.py
? bin/drtGsmScanner.py
? bin/drtLocationService.py
                                                                    hg parent gives no output and                                                                  hg update
0 files updated, 0 files merged, 0 files removed, 0 files unresolved
hg add -y * a , hence added all files

Comment: @kamal, you never committed the files it looks like, also the ones with ? aren't being tracked.

Comment: i did hg add -y * and now they all show A as a pre fix, for A AUTHORS
A CHANGES
A MANIFEST.in
A Makefile
A NEWS
A TODO
A VERSION
A bin/asteriskCallerDaemon.py
A bin/drtGsmScanner.py
A bin/drtLocationService.py

Comment: @kamal have you committed the files?